# Database Schema Help - Creating a membership site that creates memberships sites

Tags: database, schema

I'm creating a webapp where users are able to sign up and create memberships sites that will have it's own users. Here's the start of my db schema https://dl.dropbox.com/u/558799/schema.pdf

So a user can belong to many sites and a site can have many users. But the user needs to be entered as a separate user for each site so they can have different passwords and profiles. 
Example user A is a member of site A and B. User A needs to be able to change their password in site A without affecting Site B's password. I'm thinking I can add site_id as a foreign key on the user table so a user can be in it twice.

Also should I put a site_id foreign key in each table for the other tables? So every query on the webapp will have the site_id as a param. So when I'm looking up orders for for a user,I will have site_id and user_id as a params.

Is this best way to design this type of application?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps consider to move the password in to the association table.

```
user
------
user_id

site
-------
site_id

user_site
----------
user_id
site_id
password   <--- here you will get a different password per site
```

also consider adding one more id to the association table user_site_id or something - then you can use that as a key to all other references